# How can I traverse XML doc inside DOM HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I have a problem with HTML code: I want to traverse an XML document from within HTML code.

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<planner>
   <year value = "2000">

      <date month = "7" day = "15">
<note time = "1430">Doctor&apos;s appointment</note>

<note time = "1620">Physics class at BH291C</note>

</date>

<date month = "7" day = "4">

<note>Independence Day</note>

</date>

      <date month = "7" day = "20">

<note time = "0900">General Meeting in room 32-A</note>



      </date>

      <date month = "7" day = "20">

         <note time = "1900">Party at Joe&apos;s</note>

      </date>

<date month = "7" day = "20">

<note time = "1300">Financial Meeting in room 14-C</note>

</date>

   </year>

</planner>
```

and this HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<Head>
<title>Day Planner</title>
<script src="plan.xml"></script>
</head>

<body>




<form method =  "post" action = "">
<p>year : </p>
  <select id="SelectYear">
    <option selected= "selected">Select Year</option>
<option>2000</option>
  </select>


<p>Month : </p>
    <select id="Month">
      <option selected= "selected">Select Month</option>
<option>7</option>
  </select>


<p>Day : </p>

  <select id="Day">
    <option selected= "selected">Select Day</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>20</option>
  </select>


<p>Time : </p>

  <select id="SelectTime">
    <option selected= "selected">Select Time</option>
<option>0900</option>
<option>1300</option>
<option>1430</option>
<option>1620</option>
<option>1900</option>
  </select>


</br>
</br>

<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
<input type = "reset" value = "Reset" />

<p><label>your task is : <br />

</p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I get it to work?

I mean if I choose the same detail in html, how can I make appear the same task that was done on the same day?

Comment: This would help you for sure: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: I don't have skills to use JQuery

Comment: @user3123342 you don't have the ability to use jQuery in your project or you are unfamiliar with it so you won't use it? You are going to have to use javascript in some sort, you will only make it easier on yourself if you use jQuery.

Comment: Danny I'm unfamiliar with it, but tell me I am beginner I dont know where I can use JavaScript

Comment: The basic problem here is that XML is not an executable language, it is a format for storing structured data.  You can't specify an XML file as a script. Scripts have to be written in an executable language, and that usually means Javascript.  If you are unable to or unwilling to learn Javascript then you will not be able to do this task.  There's no "magic" that will make this happen for you.  At the very least you could use XSLT, but that would _still_ involve learning some Javascript, _plus_ XSLT which is another large chunk of information to assimilate.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

To parse your document so that you can put it into your webpage you do the following:

```
xmlDoc = null;
$xml = null;

$.get('file_to_read.xml', function(data) {
    var xml = data;
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui thanx but where i should put this code ?